# Organization of the items that make up the layout / composer in QGIS 3.8

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm making a map on compose. The amount of items was huge, difficult to organize.
I wonder if there is any way to create item groups, such as folders and sub folders. See figure.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried making groups and sub-groups in the working environment?
Normaly they're inherited to the layout

Comment: In map canvas yes, I use a lot of groups and subgroups. This is also possible in the legend in compose, but what I am trying to organize is the items of each element placed in the compose, for example texts, figures, maps, north symbol, scale, etc. All of these items are listed, but I can't organize them (see the picture I submitted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. That would be a nice feature, wouldn't it?

You're not the only one who thinks so. Check out [this pending feature request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/27022). Give it a thumbs up if you agree.